# A Function that will spit out the quarters to the year 3000 etc

Tags: r, date, lubridate, zoo

I need to create some code that will allow my team to have a never ending supply of the yearly quarters. i need a function that will spit out for example q1 2020 or q4 in the year 2500.

the code i have come up with so far and comments made by manager

[image]

Comment: `seq.Date(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2300-01-01"), by = "quarter")` should get you started

Comment: Please do not provide screenshots of code as part of your question. Just copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 1):

This generates a 3 column data frame with yearqtr, from date and to date columns.  The inputs can be Date, yearqtr or character objects.  In the last case it should be in the form yyyy-q as in the example.

yearqtr objects directly represent year and quarter without day and are represented internally as year + fraction where fraction is 0, 1/4, 2/4, 3/4 for the 4 quarters of a year so that adding 1/4 gives the next quarter and adding 1 gives the same quarter in the next year.

```
library(zoo)

gen_qtrs <- function(from = Sys.Date(), to) {
  qtrs <- seq(as.yearqtr(from), as.yearqtr(to), by = 1/4)
  data.frame(qtrs, from = as.Date(qtrs), to = as.Date(qtrs, frac = 1))
}
gen_qtrs(to = "2024-4")
##      qtrs       from         to
## 1 2023 Q1 2023-01-01 2023-03-31
## 2 2023 Q2 2023-04-01 2023-06-30
## 3 2023 Q3 2023-07-01 2023-09-30
## 4 2023 Q4 2023-10-01 2023-12-31
## 5 2024 Q1 2024-01-01 2024-03-31
## 6 2024 Q2 2024-04-01 2024-06-30
## 7 2024 Q3 2024-07-01 2024-09-30
## 8 2024 Q4 2024-10-01 2024-12-31
```

These would also work and give the same output:

```
gen_qtrs(to = as.Date("2024-12-31"))
gen_qtrs(to = as.yearqtr("2024-4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what format you want the input to be, but I assume you want it to be a string in the format "q3 2020". We can write a function that will be tolerant of whether the quarter comes before or after the year, and whether the "q" is uppercase or lowercase, and also allow vectorized input:

```r
getStartEndDate <- function(quarter) {
  # Convert input to lowercase letters and remove any whitespace around text
  quarter <- trimws(tolower(quarter))

  # Split the input strings by the whitespace in the middle to get
  # a list of length-2 strings, (the year and the quarter)
  quarter <- strsplit(quarter, '\\s+')

  # Only the year portion will convert from string to numeric without NAs
  # so we find this part for each pair of strings and get a vector of all 
  # the years. We throw an error if there are not two strings for each
  # item on our list, and if we fail to extract a year, sapply will return
  # a list instead of a vector so we also throw an error at this stage:
  years <- sapply(quarter, function(x) {
    if(length(x) != 2) stop('"quarter" must be a string in format "q1 2020"')
    x <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))
    x[!is.na(x)]})
  if(is.list(years)) stop('"quarter" must be a string in format "q1 2020"')
  
  # Go through our list and pick out the q1, q2, q3, or q4, converting it to
  # the number 1:4 by removing the q and calling as.numeric
  quarters <- sapply(quarter, function(x) {
    x <- grep('q(1|2|3|4)', x, value = TRUE)
    if(length(x) != 1) stop('"quarter" must be a string in format "q1 2020"')
    as.numeric(sub('q', '', x))})
  
  # Now we use Map to get a vector of quarters starting from each year, and 
  # subset the correct one using our quarters. These are made into a one-row
  # data frame for each year-quarter then all bound into a single data frame.
  do.call(rbind, Map(function(y, q) {
    dates <- seq(as.Date(paste0(y, '-01-01')), by = 'quarter', length = 5)
    data.frame(start = dates[q], end = dates[q + 1] - 1)}, y = years, q = quarters))
}
```

Testing on a simple case, we have:

```
getStartEndDate('q3 2020')
#>        start        end
#> 1 2020-07-01 2020-09-30
```

This will work for many centuries to come:

```r
getStartEndDate('q4 2500')
#>        start        end
#> 1 2500-10-01 2500-12-31
```

It can take multiple inputs in vetorised form:

```
getStartEndDate(c('q1 2023', 'q3 2024 ', 'q2 2025'))
#>        start        end
#> 1 2023-01-01 2023-03-31
#> 2 2024-07-01 2024-09-30
#> 3 2025-04-01 2025-06-30
```

It is tolerant of ordering, capitalization and accidental whitespaces:

```
getStartEndDate(c('2023 q1', 'Q3 2024 ', ' q2 2025 '))
#>        start        end
#> 1 2023-01-01 2023-03-31
#> 2 2024-07-01 2024-09-30
#> 3 2025-04-01 2025-06-30
```

And throws a helpful error message if the wrong input is received:

```r
getStartEndDate('Q3')
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
#>   "quarter" must be a string in format "q1 2020"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you so much, cant express my love for you right now

Comment: hi, i just wanted to ask if you have any comments on some of the code as its pretty complex stuff to me as im still new with r? thank you

Comment: @amaru1886 I have added extensive comments to the code